# Find and Replace Test in Multiple Files

Tags: regex, powershell, batch-file

I looked into doing this for one file and I really like the solution powershell offers:

```
Get-Content test.txt | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "foo", "bar" } | Set-Content test2.txt
```

Is there a way I can do this to get the content of a list of files, perform the same search and replace, and produce a second set of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This accomplishes what I want:

```
(Get-Content *.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "foo", "bar" } | Set-Content *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try --

```
dir *.txt | % {[IO.File]::ReadAllText($_).Replace('bar', 'test') | sc $_}
```